# Objective-c shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer disable otherGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have viewdeck controller and I can open left side-bar menu by swiping to the right. 
For my center view controller, I also have uitableview.

Problem is that I can swipe to right to open menu and I also can scroll my tableview at the same time. I need to allow only one gesture at one time.

So, I check here

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

I found out like this. I need to disable UIPanGestureRecognizer or UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer to allow only 1 gesture at one time. May I know how to do?

```
//(lldb) po gestureRecognizer
//<UIPanGestureRecognizer: 0x79eef4d0; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x79ee36e0>; target= <(action=panned:, target=<IIViewDeckController 0x79edb1d0>)>>

//(lldb) po otherGestureRecognizer
//<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x79ff32f0; state = Began; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UITableView 0x7c301e00>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UITableView 0x7c301e00>)>>
```

Comment: Hello, Dear. Can u tell us that, On which controller u have add gesture means on Tableview or on MainView.?

Comment: Yes. One gesture is from tableview and another gesture is from viewdeck controller

Comment: As I understand Your question, No need to add gesture on TableView, You have to add swipe gesture on mainView.

Comment: Yes I don't get gesture on tableview. It has automatically gestuer for uiscrollview from uitableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the `enabled` property on the other gesture recogniser to `NO`. I don't have my dev environment up at the moment but I recall having done something similar before. Like so:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizershouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    otherGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    return YES;
 }
```

Comment: This is a great idea for disabling a gesture that you're not the delegate for. However, when I try this, it doesn't take effect until the second time I invoke the gesture. The first time, the gesture still fires.

Comment: This is incorrect?  According to Apple docs, UIGestureRecognizer doesn't have the property 'enabled' and in the answer's code, the function should return a bool but does not.  This delegate method is called repeatedly whenever a recognizer attempts transition from .Possible.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/enabled Here's the enabled property which very much exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, and it solved my problem.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{ 
      if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]]) { // replace `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` with any class you don't need.
            return NO; 
      } 
      return YES; 
 }
```

Good luck. :)